# TFS: pending delete+add => file rename

Tags: tfs, rename

How do I tell TFS that pending file delete and add is actually a rename ?

For example, I deleted

201505132029594_InitialCreate.cs and tool created

201509141933543_InitialCreate.cs

I'd like to tell TFS that this was a file rename+edit. 
Ideally, from command line, something like

tf rename /someswitch 201505132029594_InitialCreate.cs 201509141933543_InitialCreate.cs

Apparently, this functionality exists in the UI (see "To fix the results of an operating system rename"):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181398(v=vs.110).aspx#fix_os_rename

Unfortunately I can't find it (nor can other people apparently)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3c909ee5-f6fa-4415-b31c-4822fc30405c/fix-the-outcome-after-you-rename-an-item-in-your-operating-system?forum=tfsversioncontrol

Comment: Are you using a server workspace or a local workspace?

Comment: @Edward, this is a server workspace (workspaces in our team are created by tool, so I never had a chance to think local vs. server)

Comment: Switching to local workspace changed available Visual Studio options under "Excluded Changes". Now I see "Detected: x add(s)" link and clicking that advertises ability to promote changes to renames. 

However, this is not a complete solution for all cases: 
- Another project has 650K files which is too much for local workspace (judging by docs).
- Would love this ability from a command line tool.

Comment: How are you pending the changes?  Are you using `tf online` or something to detect changes?

Comment: Deleting - manually in VS; adding - a tool (Entity Framework's powershell command to add new migration) adds files to Visual Studio, which ends up automatically adding them to source control (with different name but almost same content). This results in delete-add which I wanted to convert to rename. But this is just one scenario, there are other scenarios too, however they are frequently related to using tools that do not express their actions as renames. Did not have to manually detect changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can rename using the TFS API. In your case, you only need to let TFS know what happened and do not need to change anything on disk. Thus, use the [Workspace.PendRename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh725097(v=vs.120).aspx) method and specify `false` for `updatedisk`.